# Setting default Wordpress in https:// and redirecting it to http:// and forwarding http:// to https:// in Cloudflare

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

- Earlier i have set my default Wordpress install to http:// and redirected it in Cloudflare to use Https SSL, but got several **mixed content errors** on browsers[stating requests for https is http].
- So, fresh installed my whole wordpress to use https:// but i'm on a shared server with no SSL certificate installed, so now my whole site redirects to https:// and displays [Server not found error].
- I need to keep my wordpress in https:// only, in order to work with sitemaps and other plugins to access only to the https:// without conflicting.

**- So, do i need to Re-direct all https:// to http:// in .htaccess file and later redirect the http:// into cloudflare to use https://, with being my default Wordpress installed to be https://**

- Have used several rules in .htaccess but no avail, Let me know the exact rule to redirect all http:// to https://

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


  #RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If your server don't listen on the 443 Port, you can't just redirect them that way.

And if there is just an invalid certificate, there will always be the "invalid certificate" error on redirect. But it should work like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

You should try to grab an valid certificate. 
https://letsencrypt.org/ and https://www.startssl.com/ are good ways to start for free.

Comment: Thanks Kneecht.. But Ssl not allowed to be installed on my Shared server host :( Any alternatives to use https?

Comment: You could try the following:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L] `
See https://gomah.fr/server-tips/forcing-https-redirection-and-cloudflares-flexible-ssl/ for details. But please note that CloudFlare's Flexible SSL is never secure, you just "trick" the user.

Comment: This rule works, but yet https:// not redirecting or padlock pointing :( RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reviewsanswers\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.reviewsanswers.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Now you just rewrite reviewanswers.com, but not www.reviewanswers.com. That's the reason your JS / CSS is not loaded. By the way, you should try to load your CSS / JS like `//example.com/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

Did you fix the problem? Maybe you need to add this to your wp-config.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

It tells your wordpress virtual machine to use the (cloudflare) hostname on the wordpress server. If SSL is done by cloudflare this can work because traffic behind the LoadBalance ist non-ssl traffic. But I dont know Cloudflare details at all ;)

Also, you need to set the wordpress homeurl and siteurl to the https domain which your users should see.